# Kendo Grid Filtering on change Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Actually, my requirement is Whenever the user entering input in filters, the Kendo grid should display the matching records based on input.Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")

                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);

                                })
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
                                .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))

                                .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                                .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
                                .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .PageSize(20)
                                .ServerOperation(false)
                                .Events(e => e.Change("call"))


    ))


    function call(e) {

            debugger;

                    var filterlength = e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters.length;
                    var ds = $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    $filter = new Array();

                    for (var i = 0; i < filterlength; i++) {
                        if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[i].field == "Id")
                            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "eq", value: parseInt(e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value) });
                        else
                            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
                    }

                    $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = $filter;
                    $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();         



            }
```

Model.CS

```
   public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<GridData> dataList = new List<GridData>(); 
    GridData data1 = new GridData();
        data1.Id = 9191919;
        data1.Name = "XYZ";           
        dataList.Add(data1);
        return View(dataList);           
    }
```

This is working fine for strings.
But it is not working for integer columns.

Please help me.

Comment: Add your code, what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have shared the code. please help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is manage the Kendo Grid Datasource filters manually.

I already do it on my end, it's very easy, here are my helper functions, see if they help you somehow:

```
function addFilter(id, f, op) {
    var filter = $("#" + id).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter;

    if (!op) {
        op = "and";
    }

    if (filter == null) {
        filter = { logic: op, filters: new Array() };
    }

    filter.filters.push(f);

    $("#" + id).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = filter;
    return false;
}

function updateGrid(id) {
    console.log("filtering...");
    console.log($("#" + id).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter);
    $("#" + id).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($("#" + id).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter);
}


function removeFilter(tableId, fieldName) {
    var kendoGrid = $("#" + tableId).data("kendoGrid");
    if (kendoGrid == null) {
        return false;
    }
    var filterConfig = kendoGrid.dataSource._filter;
    if (filterConfig == null) {
        return false;
    }

    var iterate = function (obj) {
        //var toBeRemoved = new Array();
        var newFilters = new Array();

        $.each(obj.filters, function (key, filter) {
            if (filter.hasOwnProperty('filters')) {
                //Composite filter, recursive call
                iterate(filter);
                if (filter.filters.length) {
                    newFilters.push(filter);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (filter.field != fieldName) {
                    newFilters.push(filter);
                }
            }
        });
        obj.filters = newFilters;
    };

    iterate(filterConfig);

    if (!filterConfig.filters.length) {
        filterConfig = null;
    }

    $("#" + tableId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = filterConfig;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where and how did you call this addFilter method. Please  help me I am new to the kendo grid MVC

Comment: you hook it up to your own events and methods and call them from there:

http://pastebin.com/6YFmM56m

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
```

Try using:

```
.Filterable(i => i
.Extra(true)
.Operators(operators => operators
    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
    .StartsWith("Starts with")
    .Contains("Contains")
    .DoesNotContain("Doesn't Contain")
    .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
    .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
    ))
)
```

The default `GridFilterMode` is `Menu`. So you don't have to put that line there unless you are required to. Right now you are using both `Menu` and `Row` for the `GridFilterMode`. Normally you only use one, unless you are required to do that for some reason.

Here is what your final code would look like. You shouldn't have to use the change event, the grid will take care of the filtering.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);

                            })
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
                            .Filterable(i => i
                                .Extra(true)
                                .Operators(operators => operators
                                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                        .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                        .Contains("Contains")
                                        .DoesNotContain("Doesn't Contain")
                                        .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                                        .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                                        ))
                            )

                            .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                            .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
                            .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(20)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Events(e => 
                            {
                                //e.Change("call");
                            })
))
```

[Documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization) for Grid / Filter menu customization

Comment: Actually, my requirement is Whenever the user entering input in filters, the Kendo grid should display the matching records based on input.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you saying you want the grid to filter as the user is typing? The code above and the documentation linked will give the user a "Filter" button to click once they are done typing, which will then filter the grid.

Comment: yes I want the grid to filter as the user is typing